# Why isn't my sqlite database created?

Tags: java, sqlite, jar

I have an issue using sqlite with Java. My application, on first launch, creates a folder in the folder where is the jar file, and in that folder places my sqlite db; the problem is that when I run my project from Netbeans, all works fine without any problem, but when I build the jar and try to do it from it, the application creates the folder but not the db inside, and the program crashes. Why?
Here's the code from which I create the db and its folder:

```
public Db()
{
    if (!checker())
    {
        File f = new File("dbecprp");
        f.mkdir();
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:dbecprp/dbecprp.db";
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            s = conn.createStatement();
            s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Utente (idUtente integer primary key autoincrement, nome varchar(45) not null, email varchar(45) not null, password varchar(15) not null);");
            s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Prodotto (idProdotto integer primary key autoincrement, tipologia varchar(3) not null, titolo varchar(45) not null, creatore varchar(45) not null, prezzo float not null, descrizione varchar(45), qta_magazzino int(3) not null);");
            s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Ordine (idOrdine integer primary key autoincrement, qta_prodotto int(3) not null, totale_ordine float not null, data_ordine long not null, nome_consegna varchar(45) not null, indirizzo_spedizione varchar(150) not null, idUtente int not null, idProdotto int not null, FOREIGN KEY (idUtente) REFERENCES Utente(idUtente), FOREIGN KEY (idProdotto) REFERENCES Prodotto(idProdotto));");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Db creation failed. Program will terminate.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        filler();
    }
}

public boolean checker()
{
    File f = new File("dbecprp");
    return f.isDirectory();
}
```

Here's the clean&build output:

```
    ant -f C:\\Users\\paolo2\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Server clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 4 source files to C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build\classes
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\build
Not copying library C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\dist\lib\sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar , it can't be read.
Copy libraries to C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\dist\Server.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\paolo2\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Server\dist\Server.jar"
jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

Maybe the problem is the sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar that is not included... I used to add it manually, but maybe it doesn't work because of it.

Comment: What's in the exception which you don't care about?

Comment: If the directory already exists the code won't even try to create the database. Is this intended?

Comment: Yes, but the directory does not exist in the first launch of the application; it is made in order to check at every launch if is first launch or not

Comment: just added the clean&build output

Comment: That doesn't help. Your question was about your code not about your ant script. Have you had a look at the exceptions which you catch and don't handle?

Answer (score 0):

the database named **dbecprp.db** wont be create automatically

u need to place that **dbecprp.db**  in the **dbecprp folder** inside the project Directory

and so on...